# How to give contentDescription to SwitchPreference for Accessibilty/Talkback?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-preferences, preferencescreen, switchpreference

I have a Preference screen having multiple SwitchPreferences. I need to give custom contentDescription to each switch for accessibility.
There is no property as contentDescription for SwitchPreference. Can Anyone help me in how to give custom description to switchPreferences for Accessibilty/Talkback?

Comment: Please show us your work/code so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferences aren't views. You can't add `contentDescription` to preferences directly. You need to create a custom preference extending from `SwitchPreference` and add accessibility information to the switch view in `onBindViewHolder`.

```java
public class SwitchPreferenceAccessibility extends SwitchPreference {

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
    
    View switchView = holder.findViewById(R.id.switchWidget);
    switchView.setContentDescription(getString(R.string.accessibility_information));
  }
}
```

or you can use declare-styleable attributes, it would be more convenient.

```java
public class SwitchPreferenceAccessibility extends SwitchPreference {

  public SwitchPreferenceAccessibility(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    mContentDescription = TypedArrayUtils.getText(a, R.styleable.SwitchPreferenceAccessibility_content_description, "");
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
    
    View switchView = holder.findViewById(R.id.switchWidget);
    switchView.setContentDescription(mContentDescription);
  }
}
```

```xml
<SwitchPreferenceAccessibility
  app:key="key"
  app:title="title"
  app:content_description="@string/accessibility_information" />
```